# Storing and using ID´s from Discord on a JDA bot with "<@!ID>"

Tags: discord, bots

currently i´m creating a bot using JDA 5.0.0, and i´m trying to use and store ID´s from channels and users to send messages, my code works works only if the registered ID is not a mention, i mean, if the user doesn´t send "@UserNicknamehere" because this store in my method a ID with "<@!Useridhere>"

If i try to use this value as an ID, the bot doesn´t execute the method or function because doesn´t recognize this as an ID, my code is really simple, but i´m not sure if JDA have a solution or if i need to append the ID to get work if the value have the symbols "<@!>"

This is my simple method:

```
private void sendBotMessageToUser(String textresult) {
        //textResult is the message the bot send to user   
        String resUser = model.getUserID();
        User sendMessageToUser = api.getUserById(resUser);
        //if the user ID contains "<@!IDHERE" the method doesn´t work
        PrivateChannel privateChannel = sendMessageToUser.openPrivateChannel().complete();
        privateChannel.sendMessage(textresult).queue();
    }
```

any idea how to solve this?

i know if i delete the symbols by modifying the String before using it this going to work, but i want to know if JDA have a funcion or something can help me with this because i can´t find it.

The console log shows this exception:
20:36:53.203 [JDA MainWS-ReadThread] ERROR net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDA - One of the EventListeners had an uncaught exception
java.lang.NumberFormatException: The specified ID is not a valid snowflake (<@643462326761816114>). Expecting a valid long value!

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is you need to just send a string or long ID to `api.getUserByID()`, for example:

```java
api.getUserByID("476488167042580481");
```

If you're having trouble converting your mention into an ID, try parsing out the symbols:

```java
String userID = resUser.replaceAll("[<@!>]", "");
```

To answer your question, JDA doesn't seem to have any public-facing method to parse mentions, all I could find was [`processMentions`](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/blob/83ae9973bbe39dd692b67d7ba12ba9c12fb2ce6e/src/main/java/net/dv8tion/jda/internal/entities/mentions/AbstractMentions.java#L295), which is a protected file we cannot use. You could add your own method for parsing them instead, if you prefer.

Alternatively, go to the source of where you store or reference the mentions. JDA 5 Messages, for example, let you `.getMentions()` on the message itself and you can `.getUsers()` to find users that were mentioned, which may be better for your use case. On JDA 4, you can `.getMentionedUsers()` to the same effect.